# Hash in front of a SASS argument

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering what was the difference between :

```
@mixin transition($args...) {
  -webkit-transition: $args;
  -moz-transition: $args;
  -ms-transition: $args;
  -o-transition: $args;
  transition: $args;
}
```

and

```
@mixin transition($args...) {
  -webkit-transition: #{$args};
  -moz-transition: #{$args};
  -ms-transition: #{$args};
  -o-transition: #{$args};
  transition: #{$args};
}
```

what is the purpose of having an # in front of the argument ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#{}` syntax will interpolate the value in the curly braces into a string. This is useful, for example, in the following situations, when your variable only makes up part of the string. eg:

```
@mixin background-image($directory) {
    background-image: /#{$directory}image.jpg;
}
```

In this way, the SASS interpreter understands where the variable `$directory` ends.

If you were to do it this way, the compiler would get confused:

```
@mixin background-image($directory) {
    background-image: $directoryimage.jpg;
}
```

In your given example, it is not needed. Both versions would produce the same results.

You can do this outside of mixins as well. Consider this example using a for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .item-#{$i} { width: 2em * $i; }
}
```

Which would produce:

```
.item-1 { width: 2em; }
.item-2 { width: 4em; }
.item-3 { width: 6em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The #{} syntax in SASS is used to escape strings. Probably in your example it won't be really usefull unless you are performing really complicated stuff.

Usually you would use the escape # symbol to variabilize the names of attributes. For example to automatically create a series of themes just using lists:

```
$themes: theme1, theme2, theme3;
$colors: red, blue, green;

@mixin colorTheme($keyColor) {
  color: nth($colors, $keyColor);
}

@each $theme in $themes {
  .class-#{$theme} {
    @include colorTheme(index($themes, $theme));
  }
}
```

Would compile to:

```
.class-theme1 {
  color: red;
}

.class-theme2 {
  color: blue;
}

.class-theme3 {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: It's performing 'interpolation', it's not escaping anything.